# How can I change the width of a drop-down menu display in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: top-navigation

On my top navigation bar I have drop-down menus that display sub-menus.

The titles for the menus are wrapping around instead of displaying on one line.

I have SharePoint Designer and have open the associated master style sheet.

I've updated the ul tag to `<ul style="min-width:190px">`

But when I save and view my SharePoint page, nothing has changed.  My text in the drop-downs are still wrapping around to multiple lines.

Can some one please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is problem with text wrapping you can try below css to your style sheet

```
.menu-item-text{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The problem is no changes are applied after I save the changes.

Comment: My steps are: 1. Open my page in SharePoint designer 2013  2. open the master style sheet, 3. make my edits, 4. save

Comment: I hope this is your custom style sheet. Do you see your style sheet loading?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using !important?

```
.menu-item-text{
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```